# Get fullpath from a filename in C++

Tags: c++, windows, path, directory, filenames

I am working on an application on Windows using C/C++.
I want to know, how can I get full path of a `file/directory` from `filename/directory`?

For eg:
My filename is `test\test.txt` and actually it is located in `C:\Sample\test\test.txt`, my project is located in `E:\MyProject`.

So how can i get the full path i.e. `C:\Sample\test\test.txt` from filename `test\test.txt`.
same goes for any directory.

I have tried using GetFullPathName but it only returns `E:\MyProject\test\test.txt` which is incorrect.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you've run your executable in E:\MyProject, and want to open file from C:\Sample\test\test.txt by supplying only "test\test.txt" ? Am I correct?

Comment: If your description is accurate, well, you can't. Not without searching the entire hard drive, and there could always be duplicates.  You have a relative path.  How could you possibly add information which was never there to begin with?

Comment: Actually, `GetFullPathName` returns the right answer. Well, it returns the answer it is supposed to. But you've not yet fully specified what you want. It would seem you are asking for magic to happen. Your next step is to define your problem in a meaningful way.

Comment: Hi, Actually I am using `ReadDirectoryChangesW` to monitor file/directory and its sub directory. I have added `C:\Sample` directory to monitor, so when any modification is done to any file/directory inside it, it notifies. So what I want to know is when `test.txt` is modified, it returns me `test\test.txt` value, but I actually wants `C:\Sample\test\test.txt` value, so how can I achieve this?  Also my current working directory is `E:\MyProject`. Hope this explanation makes it clear.

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at [Boost Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#absolute).

It handles quite neatly all common path manipulations.

In your case:

```
int main()
{
  using boost::filesystem::absolute;
  using boost::filesystem::path;

  std::cout << absolute(path("test\\test.txt"), path("C:\\Sample")) << std::endl;
}
```

Note that the second argument to `absolute()` is **optional** and specifies the "current path" to use to determine the absolute path. Probably what you want in your case.

Comment: According documentation path absolute(const path& p, const path& base=current_path()); where current_path() - current working directory path. Need to modify base path according question like this absolute(path("test\\test.txt"), path("C:\\Sample"))

Comment: @Sergey: There was already a mention of the second argument but I made my answer a bit more specific. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, actually I don't know the base path i.e "C:\\Sample". I just know only one thing i.e. "test\\test.txt" and from it I need to find out the whole path, so is it possible using `absolute()` method? And one more question I have to ask is can I distribute "Boost Filesystem" library with my application to my clients, as it is for commercial use?

Comment: @JorgeChon: The link I gave you also contains an explanation on how `absolute()` operates. I believe in this case it would work like you need it to. And don't worry about Boost license: the Boost libraries can almost be considered "standard" and use a very permissive license. You can almost do whatever you want with it, and that includes use in commercial applications.

Comment: Hi, Thanks @ereOn. I am getting the following error when using the `absolute()` method -> `error: LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.lib'`. Can you please tell what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @JorgeChon: Likely you haven't linked with the boost-filesystem library. Check that you have it in the boost `lib` directory and that you configured your project to link with it. The name must match exactly and differs for release/debug and multi-threaded/mono-thread builds.

Comment: Hi, There is no boost `lib` when I have extracted the `boost_1_53_0.7z`.

Comment: @JorgeChon: Have you compiled and installed it ?

Comment: Going through the fun of linking Boost is a waste of time here. You'll end up with the same result as the trivial call to `GetFullPathName`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Actually depending on how much he needs to work with paths and how portable is code must be, it may very well **not** be a waste of time. Anyway, this was merely a suggestion, and leveraging Boost just for that might indeed seem excessive.

Comment: Hi, I have compiled `boost_1_53_0.7z` using following command `b2 link=shared --prefix=H:\Boost\boost_1_53_0 threading=single filesystem`, it compiled successfully. Now I have added following lines in my Qt project file,  `INCLUDEPATH = H:/Boost/boost_1_53_0` and `win32:LIBS += -LH:/Boost/boost_1_53_0/bin.v2/libs/filesystem/build/msvc-10.0/debug/threading-multi -lboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-gd-1_53` but it continuously gives me this error `error: LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.lib'`

Comment: Hey now the previous error has been solved. But this code `std::cout << absolute(path("test\\test.txt"), path("C:\\Sample")) << std::endl;` constantly gives me this error `main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static class std::codecvt<unsigned short,char,int> const & __cdecl boost::filesystem::path::codecvt(void)" (__imp_?codecvt@path@filesystem@boost@@SAABV?$codecvt@GDH@std@@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::filesystem::path::path<char const [32]>(char const (&)[32],void *)" (??$?0$$BY0CA@$$CBD@path@filesystem@boost)`

Comment: @JorgeChon: That is weird. Are you sure you link with the correct version of the library ? Check that you used the same compiler version, the same mode (release or debug) and the same compilation flags (especially `/MT` or `/MD`). Also you may want to ask another question about this problem to get a much broader help.